# Number of Periodic Points of the Expanding Map $E_m:S^1\to S^1$

Tags: combinatorics, dynamical-systems

**Question:** Let $\forall m: E_m:S^1\to S^1$, $x\mapsto mx (\mod{1})$ be the expanding map of the circle. What is the number of periodic points of $E_m$ of (minimal) period $n$?

**Motivation:** In Barreira & Valls' *Dynamical Systems: An Introduction* on p. 25 it is asked to show the number of periodic points of $E_m$ with period $p=q^r$ for prime $q$ and natural $r$ is $n_m(p):=m^p-m^{p/q}$. My question is a generalization of this question, where we consider not prime powers but arbitrary natural numbers.

I thought of starting with the prime factorization of $n$, but it turns out to be a messy process because we need to think of all combinations. Any ideas or elegant proofs are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of [Möbius inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula).  The number of points with period *dividing* $n$ is $m^n$, so if $f_m(n)$ denotes the number of points with period *exactly* $n$, we have
$$m^n = \sum_{d|n} f_m(d),$$
where the sum runs over all divisors of $d$.  The Möbius inversion formula then tells us that
$$f_m(n)=\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) m^{n/d},$$
where $\mu(d)$ is $0$ if $d$ is divisible by a square, else $(-1)$ raised to the number of prime factors of $d$.  In particular $\mu(q)=-1$ for any prime $q$, which gives the special case you mentioned.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you.